# How to change rgb values with only x and y position

Tags: c, linux, rgb, cartesian-coordinates

I was wondering how I could map RGB values to xy-coordinates. For example, in some applications, I have seen circles where moving the cursor within that circle would change rgb values evenly.

In my case, I have a square area and I would like to map an xy coordinate within that area to rgb value. I would only expect that RGB values would ne in the range [0, 255] given the xy area which lets say the values for x and y would be in the range [0, 100]. Also expect a gradual change in color so for example (1,1) could be (255, 0, 0) and a change in xy to (1,2) would result in a similar rgb (254, 1, 0) rather than a completely different color (129, 244, 65)

Can someone show me the math behind this? Better yet, some c code?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'm afraid I have no idea what you are asking: Are you looking for code that takes some x, y coordinates and calculates some color from that? If so, what are your expectations on that color and how it should depend on the coordinates?

Comment: Hi. Yes that is exactly what I'm looking for. I would only expect that RGB values would range from 0-255 given the xy area which lets say the values for x and y would be 0-100. Also expect a gradual change in color so for example (1,1) could be (255, 0, 0) and a change in xy to (1,2) would result in a similar rgb (254, 1, 0) rather than a completely different color (129, 244, 65)

Answer (score 2):

I would convert from [rectangular to polar](http://mathwords.com/p/polar_rectangular_conversion_formulas.htm) and use [HSL or HSV color](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) instead of RGB color .

It will be naturally smooth, which you can see if you look at the HSL/HSV graphics (the circular ones), at the URL (see the smooth transition).  Once you get those x/y values converted which you should be able to figure out on your own by searching, the resulting values should be able to index into a hue color pretty easily for a smooth transition effect.

And as for the C code, just the basic math is straight forward but the actual setting of color is dependent on the platform you're writing the C code on, which you have not disclosed or, better yet, specified with the appropriate tag so the appropriate developers here can see it.

**Here is an** [HSV -> RGB conversion algorithm in C](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ncs/color/t_convert.html)

Comment: thanks for the response. I am developing on linux and unfortunately I need to use RGB

Comment: Why?  What windowing or graphics system are you using?  Why the limitation to RGB?

Comment: I've added a link to an RGB to HSV conversion algorithm in C

Comment: Interpolating HSV would produce a different gradient. For example if the gradient goes from blue to red and you linearly interpolate the hue component, the color will be green in the middle.

Comment: What's the linear part if it's been converted to polar coordinates first?

Comment: The hue component would linearly change along an arc, producing a color wheel effect, and not a linear gradient between two end colors.

Comment: Color wheel effect like this?  https://color.adobe.com/build2.0.0-buildNo/resource/img/kuler/color_wheel_730.png  Wouldn't your interpolation be applicable to HSV as well? There it looks like you'd want to reduce the weight given to the primary colors as you moved the around the circle and increase the weight of the yellow, Magenta (e.g. combined colors) whatever they're called.

Answer (score 1):

RGB values can be linearly combined component-wise to create gradient effects. Say you want to pass from a color `(r1, g1, b1)` to another color `(r2, g2, b2)`. All the intermediary colors in an RGB gradient would be `((1-a)*r1 + a*r2, (1-a)*g1 + a*g2, (1-a)*b1 + a*b2)`, where `a` varies from 0 to 1.

To calculate the color at each point `p=(x,y)` along a linear gradient from point `p1=(x1,y1)` to point `p2=(x2,y2)`, you would calculate the dot product of `p1 p` and `p1 p2` and divide it by the norm of `p1 p2` and by the norm of `p1 p`, and clamp the value to the interval `[0,1]`.

For a radial gradient on a circle of center `c` and radius `rad`, you would calculate `a = distance(p, c) / r`, and clamp to `[0, 1]`.

Which intermediary colors appear depends on the used color space (RGB, HSV, HSL, etc) (still interpolated component-wise.) See http://howaboutanorange.com/blog/2011/08/10/color_interpolation/

Example code (pseudocode, not tested):

```
struct rgb_color {
    float r, g, b;
};
struct vec {
    float x, y;
};

// Color at point p, for a linear RGB gradient from point a (with color a_col) to b (with color b_col)    
rgb_color linear_gradient(vec p, vec a, rgb_color a_col, vec b, rgb_color b_col) {
    vec ab = { b.x - a.x, b.y - a.y };
    vec ap = { p.x - a.x, p.y - a.y };
    float ab_norm = sqrt(ab.x*ab.x + ab.y*ab.y);
    float ap_norm = sqrt(ap.x*ap.x + ap.y*ap.y);

    float dot = ab.x*ap.x + ab.y*ap.y;
    k = dot / (ab_norm * ap_norm);
    if(k < 0.0) k = 0.0;
    else if(k > 1.0) k = 1.0;

    float r = (1.0-k)*a_col.r + k*b_col.r;
    float g = (1.0-k)*a_col.g + k*b_col.g;
    float b = (1.0-k)*a_col.b + k*b_col.b;
    return { r, g, b };
}

// Color at point p, for a radial RGB gradient from for circle with center c (with color c_col), radius, and color outer_col outside the circle.
rgb_color radial_gradient(vec p, rgb_color c_col, vec c, float radius, rgb_color outer_col) {
    vec pc = { c.x - p.x, c.y - p.y };
    float pc_norm = sqrt(pc.x*pc.x + pc.y*pc.y);

    float k = pc_norm / radius;
    if(k < 0.0) k = 0.0;
    else if(k > 1.0) k = 1.0;

    float r = (1.0-k)*c_col.r + k*outer_col.r;
    float g = (1.0-k)*c_col.g + k*outer_col.g;
    float b = (1.0-k)*c_col.b + k*outer_col.b;
    return { r, g, b };
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the second paragraph. What does p consist of? p = (r,g,b) and p1,p2 = (x,y)? how do I determine what color belongs at a specific point say (0, 50) ?

Comment: If it were me, considering that you want the users to see color transitions, but they are probably not purists and won't see all the colors at once and feel 'cheated', I would start with basic HSV and get a color wheel effect, then figure out how to add a heuristic to fudge or interpolate the numbers based on which part of the circle they were riding over, unless or until I found a very clear formula for doing otherwise.  Because the color wheel approaches the effect you want, but it just emphasizes the primary colors over a larger range than idea for constant change.

Comment: YES! the color wheel effect is essentially what I'm after.

Comment: I don't want to diss the ideas laid out by @tmlen I think he knows more about this stuff overall than I do, and was getting you on the right track abstractly.  But the question is, is the HSV / colorwheel approach easier to figure out/implement while being 'good enough for who it's for'?  I'm not an expert, this is just how I would approach the problem until a better and clear solution came along.

Comment: Added some example on how to calculate linear and radial gradient. For a gradiant that changes with the angle around a point you would need trigonometric formula, i.e. conversion to polar coordinates.